# Make list of strings uppercase and fill up strings with less than 5 characters

Tags: python, for-loop

I am a few weeks into learning python properly and couldn't find a way to proceed or fix from what I currently have. The question is:

> Write a function squigler(strings) which takes a list of strings as a parameter and modifies that list by replacing each string with the upper-case version of itself AND filling up any strings that have less than 5 characters with enough '#' characters to make them exactly 5 characters long.

> Hints: 1. You will need to use the updated-list pattern, and remember you don't need to explicitly return a value. 2. The appropriate str method will come in handy here.

My code so far:

```
def squigler(strings):
    result = []
    for string in strings:
        split = strings.split().upper()
        if len(split) < 5:
            char = 5 - len(split)
            result.append(char * '#')
        else:
            for string in strings:
                result.append(string)
            
    return result
```

Test code:

```
strings = ['Right', 'SAID', 'jO']
squigler(strings)
print(strings)
```

EXPECTED CODE:

```
['RIGHT', 'SAID#', 'JO###']
```

Thank you.

Comment: What output are you getting? Edit this into the question because without it you are expecting readers to work this out themselves.

Comment: What output do you expect exactly? Should `SAID` be `#SAID` or `SAID#`?

Comment: Yeah sorry expected output is added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointing out the mistakes/unnecessary lines in your code:

- The line `split = strings.split().upper()` is erroneous and at the same time unnecessary as you are mistakenly using `strings` *(list)* instead of `string` *(string literal)*. Also, you can use `len(string)` directly instead of splitting the string into a list and finding the length of list.
- `result.append(char * '#')` is just appending **"#"** but not the actual string. The line could be rewritten as `result.append(string.upper() + char * '#')`

Thus, your code can be *re-written* as following:

```
def squigler(strings):
    result = []
    for string in strings:
        if len(string) < 5:
            char = 5 - len(string)
            result.append(string.upper() + char * '#')
        else:
            result.append(string.upper())
            
    return result
```

An **elegant** way to achieve this would be the following:

```
def squigler(strings):
    return list(map(lambda x: x.upper().ljust(5, '#'), strings))
```

### Testing the Output

```
# TEST
strings = ['Right', 'SAID', 'jO']
strings = squigler(strings)  # Over-writes the original `strings` list

print(strings)  # Output: ['RIGHT', 'SAID#', 'JO###']
```

> Here, `map` function loops over all the elements in the list `strings` and
> applies `lambda` function that we provided as an argument to `map` to each of
> these elements and returns a `map` object which we then convert to `list` and
> return it.
>
> `ljust` method of string, pushes the string to the left and appends a given character at the end of the string which would make the string exactly n characters long *(in this case n=5)*

### EDIT:

In your case, since you are not allowed to change the test code, there's an alternative in which you change the value of the list in-place instead of returning a new list...

```
def squigler(strings):
    for(index,  string) in enumerate(strings):
        if len(string) < 5:
            char = 5 - len(string)
            strings[index] = string.upper() + char * '#'
        else:
            strings[index] = string.upper()
```

> Here, you are changing the values of the list index-by-index
> instead of returning a new list and reassigning the old one.

Comment: Hey thanks for taking the time, however, neither of the codes are outputting the desired code with my test code compared to your test code? They look like they do the same thing so why is outputting just original list. Also, the rewritten code does not contain the uppercase requirement.

Comment: I have edited the code so that it can convert the strings to uppercase. Also, you need to write `strings = squigler(strings)` if you want to change the original list, since the function returns a new list without updating the original list

Comment: Are you able to edit the so that it has an updated-list pattern? Sorry if I'm being fussy but its a requirement for this particular question I think as I cannot change the test code

Comment: @walrus1234 You can check the updated code now...

Comment: When submitting a question I cannot change the test code? Is it possible to rewrite the code without changing the test code?

Comment: Check out the EDIT section. That should be enough for your case...

Answer (score 2):

Python has handy methods to do just this! You can go for a pythonic approach-

```py
def squigler(strings):
    for i, string in enumerate(strings):
        strings[i] = string.upper().ljust(5, '#')
```

### Output

```py
>>> squigler(['Right', 'SAID', 'jO'])
>>> print(strings)
['RIGHT', 'SAID#', 'JO###']
```

### How does this work?

- [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#enumerate) lets you iterate through a string while having both the index of each element and the element itself, it's the same as a `range` loop except you don't have to index the list to get the element
- [`str.upper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) converts all characters in a string to its respective uppercase version
- [`str.ljust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) pads the string to a given length, with the given characters, on the right. This will fill on the right side (`rjust` fills on the left side)

Also, I'm not a fan of mutating the argument of a function inside the function, especially in this case. So if you ever want to just return a new list instead of mutating, you can do this even more elegantly.

With regular, but pythonic as always, [list comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/)

```py
def squigler(strings):
    return [string.upper().ljust(5, '#') for string in strings]
```

Or even use a [lazy generator](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/)

```py
def squigler(strings):
    return (string.upper().ljust(5, '#') for string in strings)
```

Or use a [lambda function](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions)

```py
lambda strings: (string.upper().ljust(5, '#') for string in strings)
```

You can now store that lambda function in a variable and use it, functional style!

```py
>>> f = lambda strings: (string.upper().ljust(5, '#') for string in strings)
>>> f(strings)
```

All elegant methods of achieving this in a pythonic way!

Answer (score 1):

```
def squigler(strings):
    
    for i in range(len(strings)):
        s = strings[i].upper()
        if len(s) < 5:
            s = s + '#' * (5 - len(s))

        strings[i] = s # Replace in array itself.
            

strings = ['Right', 'SAID', 'jO']
squigler(strings)
print(strings)
```

Output:

```
['RIGHT', 'SAID#', 'JO###']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use str.ljust()

```
>>> s = "hello"
>>> s.upper().ljust(10,"#")
'HELLO#####'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scikit-learn?sort=Newest&filters=NoAnswers&uqlId=27990)